# solve coupled second-order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

How can I solve the following set of coupled 2nd order differential equations?
\begin{equation}
\ddot{x}_{1}= -a^{2}x_{1}+ b^{2}x_{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\ddot{x}_{2}= b^{2}x_{1}-c^{2}x_{2}
\end{equation}
How can I solve for ${x}_{1}$ and ${x}_{2}$ in this case? I tried to calculate the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the matrix of coefficients but I am completely confused with the algebra. I am a beginner in differential equations.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

With the eigenvectors for

$$
A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}-a^2 & b^2\\b^2 & -c^2\end{array}\right)
$$

calling

$$
T = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{c^2-a^2-\sqrt{4 b^4+\left(a^2-c^2\right)^2}}{2 b^2} & 1 \\
 \frac{c^2-a^2+\sqrt{4 b^4+\left(a^2-c^2\right)^2}}{2 b^2} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and making $X = T^{-1}Y$ we have

$$
T^{-1}\ddot Y = A T^{-1}Y
$$

and then

$$
\ddot Y = T A T^{-1} Y = \Lambda Y
$$

so the new system reads

$$
\ddot y_1 = \lambda_1 y_1\\
\ddot y_2 = \lambda_2 y_2
$$

Here

$$
\lambda_1 = -\frac 12\left(a^2+c^2+\sqrt{(a^2-c^2)^2-4b^4}\right)\\
\lambda_2 = -\frac 12\left(a^2+c^2-\sqrt{(a^2-c^2)^2-4b^4}\right)
$$

Comment: If I understood it correctly, I would get 
\begin{equation}
y_{1}= ke^{\sqrt{\lambda_{1}}t} + le^{ -\sqrt{\lambda_{1}}t}
\end{equation}. where k and l are constants. Eventually, I expect an expression with cosine or sine terms. How can I bring it into this form? And is $y_{1} = x_{1}$ or do I have to do a similarity transformation?

Comment: @MrDerDart The occurrence of $\sin, \cos$ depends for instance, on the value of $\Delta =(a^2-c^2)^2-4b^2$. If $\Delta < 0$ then the solution will exhibit terms as $e^{\alpha t}\cos(\beta t), e^{\alpha t}\sin(\beta t)$